# Single word for undo / redo capability

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, software

I'm looking for a single word that describes an application that provides the capability to redo or undo steps. My first thoughts were something like *modifiable software*, which doesn't really suit my needs, or things like *step-tracking software*. But all these sound a bit wrong or not on-the-spot.

Is there something better?

Comment: Change Tracking or History?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need some variant of "Versioning" or "History", but if you can get away with multiple words, your original undo/redo is well understood by most computer users.

Comment: It's not important that most computer users understand it, it's meant to be used in sourcecode. I'm effectively looking for a name of the interface (how **I** should name it) that provides this capability.

Comment: In that case, I'd call it "history". You might get a good answer if you ask this over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ also.

Comment: "History" should be well understood in this context. Cf. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/local_history.html

Answer (score 2):

All user actions are **reversible**.

Def: [Reversible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reversible)

More generally: [Reversibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversibility_%28disambiguation%29)

Comment: Sounds more like something I'd want... Except that it's not only reversible, it's also the opposite (using the redo mechanism)

Answer (score 0):

Revertible

adjective
1.
able to be returned to a previous state.